# Google Font, where to put the href link in the html sheet?

Tags: html, fonts

I am currently using 2x google fonts for my website.

The words that is styled with these google fonts seems to be render very slow, I have placed the **http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>** at the bottom of the page, to make Google Pagespeed Insights happy.

But when I read at the Google Font page, it says, place it right after the 1st line in your head tag.

So my question is, should I follow the Google Font recommendation or the Insight one?

Thanks Jack

Comment: I usually include fonts in the header

Comment: So, breaking the Google Page Insight recommendation, is the best way to go?

Comment: Just comes down to the way your code is setup, and what you want to be loaded first/last. If including the fonts in the footer is working and the fonts are being applied where you want them, then it should be fine to keep it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be in the first line in your head tag. 
Google give some insight as to the impact any font will have on page load times.
What you are actually doing by having them at the bottom is rendering your page in one font then rendering it again with the Google font.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place in `<head></head>` and not in the `<body></body>`